# ¿Por que no puedo visualizar correctamente el editor de pregunta en el sitio en español?

Tags: soporte, bug

Presento el siguiente problema desde hace unos 3 dias.

No puedo visualizar los botones del editor de pregunta:

1) Vaciar el dns (habia realizado un cambio de google dns a 1.1.1.1, luego lo reverti)

2) Verificar el certificado de es.stackoverflow.com, estaba correcto

3) Verificar que hiciera ping al sitio, regreso 151.101.65.69

4) Verificar errores en consola al principio daba estos:

[image: titulo]

Luego de reiniciar chrome, no aparecio ninguno.

5) Intente en microsoft edge aparecieron estos errores:

[image: titulo]

6) Trate entrando a mi pregunta en el sitio en ingles y si me funciona correctamente.

7) Navegadores probados: Chrome y Microsoft Edge.

8) Sistema operativo windows 10 x64

NOTA: El problema ocurre en mi trabajo, el internet nos viene de la sucursal principal.

FOTO DEL PROBLEMA:
[image: titulo]

Actualización:

Probé en un equipo windows 7 y persiste el problema, creo que puede ser el servicio de internet, ha estado funcionando de manera deficiente.

Comment: Es muy raro ese "Powered by AMP", nunca usamos AMP en SO. Y g3rv4 no es moderador del sitio así que no le creas nada.

Comment: A mi también me ha ocurrido ese problema, aunque, usando el mismo navegador, hay pequeños momentos en los que desaparece y luego vuelve a aparecer. Hay momentos en que tengo que refrescar varias veces la página para que reaparezcan los botones.

Comment: En general, es una buena idea no creer nada de lo que dice @g3rv4 ;)

Comment: Intenta usando el navegador en modo de navegación incógnito con todas las extensiones inhabilitadas y usando otro equipo.

Comment: Todo tiene pinta de que es algún bloqueo de tu red corporativa (o de la persona o grupo que la administra), intenta replicar el escenario con el mismo equipo pero en una red distinta, el problema ya no debería presentarse

Comment: Creo que el error se soluciono, porque ya puedo visualizar correctamente el editor, nos informaron que estaban haciendo unas pruebas por mantenimiento.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un problema que no se puede reproducir

Comment: @Phi debería eliminarla o cerrarla?

Comment: @VictorAlvarado Considero que solo cerrarla, es un problema ajeno al sitio pero que podría servir de referencia por si a alguien más le llega a pasar en el futuro